# How could this class be made unit testable?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oop

I have a class which implements a specialized buffer kind of collection. 
To me it seems like the Flush method for example is not unit testable. If I, for one, would like to test what happens if I add data, Flush it, add data again and then Flush it again to see if I only get the data back that was added after the first Flush. For me to be able to do that I'd have to use the Add method, too. Is using another method in a test that is part of the tested class and should be unit tested separately a bad practice? Is this class even unit testable? Questions like these pop up and I can't answer them. Thanks in advance!

```
public class DataBuffer : IDataBuffer
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>> buffer;

    public DataBuffer()
    {
        buffer = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>();
    }

    public void Add(string type, Dictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        if (!buffer.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            buffer[type] = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        }
        buffer[type].Add(metrics);
    }

    public Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>> Flush()
    {
        var result = buffer;
        buffer = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>();

        return result;
    }

    public int Count(string type) => buffer[type].Count;
}
```

Basically I'd like to write a unit test like this. Does this seem like a valid one?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Flush_NoDataIsGivenBackTwice()
    {
        var data1 = new Dictionary<string, object>
        { 
            { "key1", "value1" } 
        };
        dataBuffer.Add("type", data1);

        var result1 = dataBuffer.Flush();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, result1["type"].Count);
        Assert.AreSame(data1, result1["type"].First());

        var data2 = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "key2", "value2" }
        };
        dataBuffer.Add("type", data2);

        var result2 = dataBuffer.Flush();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, result2["type"].Count);
        Assert.AreSame(data2, result2["type"].First());
    }
```

Comment: It's perfectly valid to call other class methods in the *Arrange* phase of a test. Then, in the *Act* phase you are supposed to call what you want to test, in this case, the `Flush` method. Then, *Assert* follows.

Comment: thank you for your comment! I've added an example unit test with which I'd like to test a functionality that is very important.

Comment: The test looks ok to me. Assuming there are other tests to test corner cases, this one is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this class should not be easy to test. I think I would like to challenge you on some implementation choices.

Why do you give back the current state of affairs before creating an new instance?
I think a `Flush()` / `Clear()` method should just be a void.

Why do you you not just apply `Clear()` on the underlying buffer and make the field readonly?

Why are your not more defensive on `Count(string type)`? I would argue that should do something like this:

```
public int Count(string type)
{
    if(buffer.TryGet(type, out List<Dictionary<string, object>> subset)
    {
        return subset.Count;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

I would aslo expect the use of `TryGet()` in the `Add()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With Flush I'd like to Give back the data and Clear my Buffer. It is basically a GetAndClear method. I've implemented it with this kind of reference swap because it should be much faster than creating a new Dictionary with its copy constructor. This collection could potentially have many items up to 15MBs in size and I don't want to copy that every time.

Comment: Well, in that case: rename the method to make its intent clear. And then you might also want to be thread-safe, so you might want to start implementing some locking to prevent issues.

Comment: You should (in general) try to have tread safety (if required) on the lowest level possible, as it allows to keep the lock smaller.

Comment: I could not easily synchronize Adding and Flushing elements on the "Buffer" level. Both can happen basically at any time through multiple threads

Comment: Just use a locker:

    public class DataBuffer : IDataBuffer
    {
        public Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>> GetAndClearBluffer()
        {
            lock(locker)
            {   
                var result = buffer;
                buffer = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>();
                return result;
            }
        }
        private readonly object locker = new object();
    }